# Crystal Reports one is to many relationship

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I'm not really sure how to phrase my title so I would just explain the situation that I have. I'm relatively new at crystal reports and basically all I know how to do in it is to show linear collections where you have a dataset and you just present all the fields that you want from it and basically the fields have 1..1 relationship.  However, I am trying to do a report where there can be a 0..n relationship in between the fields and will break the linear nature of the report.  For example:

I have 3 sets of collections as follows with their respective properties:

**Contributions**

- ContributionMonth
- ContributionAmount

**Remittances**

- ContributionMonth
- RemittancePeriod
- Amount

**Forfeitures**

- ContributionMonth
- ForfeiturePeriod
- Amount

For each contribution it can have 0..n Remittances and/or Forfeitures related to it. So there would be cases where a report should look something like this:

**ContriMonth** || **ContriAmt** ||  **RemitPeriod** || **Amount** || **ForfPeriod** || **Amount**

January 2010 || 954.23-----   || 1Q2010-------   ||   500.00---||-----------------||

------------------||---------------|| 2Q2010--------|| 250.00---||-----------------||

February 2010||5000.00---|| -------------------|| -----------|| 2Q2010-------|| 550.00

-------------------||-------------|| -------------------|| -----------|| 3Q2010-------|| 750.00

I've tried using formulas where you show the remit and forfeit details something like

```
if({ContributionDetails.ContributionMonth} =         {RemittancesEmployerMonthly.ContributionMonth})
then
{RemittancesEmployerMonthly.TotalEmployerRemittance}
else 
    0.00
```

but it creates an inner join wherein it only shows contributions that have remittances and skips the values that have no remittances/forfeitures

how do i go about doing this format?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the data source for these "collections" - is it a relational database, or some other data source?

Comment: Well.. it's actually from a database, the "collections" are passed through a dataset that contains the results of multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the joins between the tables are either "left outer joins" or "right outer joins".  I think you require left outer joins in this case.  This will return data from the main table, even if data is not present in the other tables.

You can set this in `Database Expert` and then the `Links` tab.  You can change a link by right clicking on it.

You will then need to create appropriate groups (ContriMonth) to group the returned data by.  You will also need to check for null values in your formulas in cases there is no data present.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input! I didn't know that you could right click on the link. After I did that, the result set looks like the result when you perform a straightforward left join between the tables wherein it would show every possible combination of Contributions with Remittances and Forfeitures. However, I can't seem to figure out how to use the group expert. I mean, it looks straightforward enough that i just select to group by the ContriMonth column but the only difference that I can see is that they separate the results in sections. Is there a specific trick to it?